# clang-14: error: unsupported option '--no-entry'

Tags: c, macos, clang, llvm

When running the command:

```
clang --target=wasm32 -nostdlib -Wl, --no-entry -Wl, --export-all howold.c -o howold.wasm
```

I get the following errors:

```
clang-14: error: unsupported option '--no-entry'
clang-14: error: unsupported option '--export-all'
```

I installed LLVM using `brew install llvm` and linked it properly with `brew link llvm`, then ran `source .zshrc`.

Does macOS not support these directives or am I missing an install or command somewhere? I am new to LLVM and clang on macOS so this may be an installation problem but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass arguments to the linker, there shouldn't be a space after `-Wl,`. With the extra space, you're trying to give the `--no-entry` option to `clang` itself, which isn't valid.

Try this:

```
clang --target=wasm32 -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export-all howold.c -o howold.wasm
```